# SSRS Report - Subreport can't be found

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, subreport

Ok, I have an SSRS report that has 2 subreports in it.  One works just fine and the other works in testing but when I publish the report to my AMS platform under their instructions, the subreport comes up saying it can't be found.  I can run the report through Visual Studio and it works just fine without a problem and I have rebuilt the entire project a few times and republished but I still keep getting the same error.  I know that the publishing is working because I made a change to the main report to expand the subreport area and allow me to see the full error and that published fine.  Any reason this would work through Visual Studio but not when published?  The report along with the 2 subreports all are in the same directory as well.

Additional note to this. I just went to the master report in Visual Studio and deleted the subreport from it. I then re-added it and gave it a different name. Rebuilt the report and re-uploaded it including the already uploaded sub report and I am getting the same error but the error is referring to the new name I gave the subreport so it picked up the name change but not the actual sub report for some reason

Comment: You should add this comment to your question really, anyway... Did you actually deploy the subreport as well as the main report? Have you tried opening the subreport on it's own from the server?

Comment: Added additional comment to main post.  Thanks for catching that.

Yes, I did deploy the subreport with the main report and I can run it on its own on the server without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes SSRS website caches your old report and doesn't get overridden by your new reports. On the SSRS website, try removing all of your reports including the main report. Then re-deploy.